# Suma de números binarios en haskell y recursividad

Tags: lista, recursión, haskell

***Hola que tal espero puedan ayudarme
Tengo que realizar una funcion de suma de numeros binarios de dos listas y haciendo la suma de derecha a izquierda como si se hiciera la suma a mano, he realizado esta funcion pero ya estoy estancado, alguna idea?
esto es lo que llevo***

````
```
suma :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
suma xs [] = xs
suma [] ys = ys
suma [] [] = []
suma xs ys =
        | last xs + last ys == 0 = 0:[0] suma init xs init ys     
        | last xs + last ys == 1 = 1:[] suma init xs init ys
        | last xs + last ys == 2 = 1:[0]
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas un argumento más para llevar el *"acarreo"*. Inicialmente será 0 y hay que tenerlo en cuenta en el caso final:

```
suma :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
suma xs [] ac = if ac == 0 then xs else suma xs [1] 0
suma [] ys ac = if ac == 0 then ys else suma ys [1] 0
suma xs ys ac = suma (init xs) (init ys) ac' ++ [d]
  where
    v = last xs + last ys + ac
    (ac', d) = divMod v 2
```

De todos modos, la mejor forma sería mediante un *plegado* usando `foldr`, pero creo que es algo complicado para lo que estás ahora viendo.

Comment: amigo no manches muchas gracias de verdad estaba perdido, me puedes decir si me puedes cobrar para enseñarme mientras realizamos un código de suma y multiplicación de matrices.

Comment: No estoy disponible. De todos, por aquí estaré para ayudar en lo que sea posible.